# find specific property inside array of object

Tags: javascript

I use the following code and I want to find if path is equal to some key
I try with the following loops without success,what am I doing wrong here?

I need to find if key is exist

https://jsfiddle.net/0ukL2jxh/

```
var obj = {
    "prov": [{
        "save": {
            "key": "aaa",
            "method": "sa"
        },
        "delete": {
            "key": "bbb",
            "method": "del"
        }
    }]
};

var obj2 = {
    "prov": [{
        "save": {
            "key": "ccc",
            "method": "sa"
        },
        "delete": {
            "key": "ccc",
            "method": "del"
        }
    }]
};

var myArray = [];
myArray.push(obj);
myArray.push(obj2);

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    var configObj = configs[i];

    for (var j = 0; configObj; j++) {
        var prov = configObj[j];

        for (var x = 0; prov; x++) {
            var obj = prov[x];

            for (var y = 0; obj; y++) {
                  if (obj.key === 'aaa')
                      exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about mapping your array objects into keys only (extracting the keys from your objects), then doing a simple array search for a given element ?

```
var keys = myArray.map(function(e, i){
   return e.prov[0].save.key;
});

// keys = ["aaa", "ccc"]

// will give you the index of the element, -1 if does not exist
var index = keys.indexOf("ccc");
```

in your example, you would do

```
if (index > -1)
   exit; // although I do not recognize such javascript statement :-)
```

---

**Update**:

Well, after some additional explanations from your side, the problem became clearer.

I think this is what you need:

```
function f(array, keyName, keyValue) {
   function findKey(obj) {
       var keyFound = false;

       for(var property in obj) {
          if (property == keyName && obj[property] == keyValue) {
             return true;
          }
          else if(typeof(obj[property]) == "object") {
            keyFound = findKey(obj[property], property);
            if (keyFound)
               return keyFound;
          }
          else {
            if (obj == keyValue)
               keyFound = true;
          }
       }       


       return keyFound;
   }
   var keyFound = false;
   for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       keyFound = findKey(array[i]);
       if (keyFound)
          break;
   }

   return keyFound;
}

//usage:
//f(myArray, "delete", "method") -> false
//f(myArray, "keydasd", "aaa") -> false
//f(myArray, "key", "aaa") -> true
//f(myArray, "method", "del") -> true
```

**function 'f' Parameters**:

obj => your array containing objects

keyName => the name of the key to search for a matching value

keyValue => the value of the key...

**Just for the record**:
Thanks to you I learned that you could make a generic solution for this problem, creating a function like

```
function f(obj, objPath, keyValue)
```

where you objPath can be whatever path to the key you want to search for a matching value, in the form of a string. Then using `eval`, you can access obj's matching value

```
eval (obj[objPath])
```

Here's an example of such a thing:

```
var o = { 
   a: 1,
   b: {
     c: [
       {
       x: "xxx",
       y: 1205
      },
      {
       x: 1020,
       y: 8274
      }
     ],
     d: 1000
   }
}

var p1 = "o.b"
var p2 = ".c[0].x"

eval(p1 + p2)
//result: "xxx"
```

Comment: Thanks but the save is hardcoded and I've also delete and it can be other string,so how can I adopt your example?

Comment: turning this code into a function that receives a parameter. Will update my answer

Comment: Thanks 1+ for the effort ,I try your first solution after the update and there is a way to avoid the parentKeyToSearchIn? this is come dynmacllaiy from the object...I need to find just if aaa is in this structure that it ,if yes exit the function and return true, the structure of the object is constant the value can be changed...like aaa bbb

Comment: Just need to know if key ccc or aaa etc are in this object which is all the time have property key....\

Comment: I am working on a more elegant solution, will post it here soon. Have been busy now

Comment: Thanks, I will test it soon,there is other elegenat way to access the object ,I mean not using eval?

Comment: I test it and the only issue is with this statment  if (property == keyName && obj[property] == keyValue) {
             return true;
          }

Comment: in this case when the value is found why not to exit all the function with true, when the value (keyValue)is found exit all the process with true...Thanks for the support!

Comment: Do not understand what the issue is - there is a return true there, meaning it leaves findKey() with true (as you want) ? Keep in mind that findKey will be in the middle of recursive chain calls to findKey() (meaning, upon leaving the function with true, it has to go all the way up in the recursive chain, to the outermost/initial call so the process ends) Are there specific cases when the function return incorrect values ? could you post them ?